# How can I speed up PHPs FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I'm working on a Debian Server, 16 GB RAM, QuadCore, GBitLan and so on...not worth talking about.

I have a problem with the speed of the upload via PHP `ftp_put (...)` function.
If I transfer a file with 4 GiB filesize from local to local, only a unrealistic test I know, it takes with the native FTP 36 seconds (133 MB/s) and with `ftp_put(...)`, same maschine, more than 4 minutes (~13MB/s).

So my question is
- why is  PHPs `ftp_put(...)` so slow
- and how can I speed it up ?

- [Here are both screenshots of the native and PHP FTP output](http://pbrd.co/L5KhvB)
- [The PHP Function](http://pastebin.com/9d7GTp8k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that the native ftp client short-circuits the download (which would normally go through the entire TCP/IP protocol stack) to an internal copy? 133 MB/s seems quite high to me, but then again I don't own a 2000$ server. You could verify this by using a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (I think you can even see your bandwidth usage in `taskmgr.exe` on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, but it would be nice for further reading that you supply the final answer. Did the native FTP indeed  short-circuited the TCP/IP protocol stack?